# Python : How to drop and save records from df except few columns?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Last_Name': ['Jolly', Null, Sam,'Ronnie'], 
       'First_Name': ['Jack', Null, 'Bill', 'Tony'],
       'Age': [55, 65, Null, 70], 'Salary':[500,800,Null,Null})

Expected output :
df_drop = pd.DataFrame({'Last_Name': ['Sam', Ronnie,], 
       'First_Name': ['Bill', Tony,],
       'Age': [Null, 70], 'Salary':[Null,Null})
```

Saving the dropped records in variable 'df_drop'. I am expecting such output. I dont want to apply drop function to 'Last_name' and 'First_name'. Do you have suggestion where I can save drop records by selecting columns. Am doing something like below but didnt work. Please suggest

```
df_drop = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
df.dropna(subset = [2,3], inplace = True)
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: _Am doing something like below but didnt work._ What does that mean, exactly? What are those `Null` values? Please provide an actual [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If want remove missing rows by all columns without `Last_Name` and `First_Name` use [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) with [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for select rows with at least one `NaN`:

```
df_drop = df[df.drop(['Last_Name','First_Name'], axis=1).isna().any(axis=1)]
```

Or if want not check first 2 columns use:

```
df_drop = df[df.iloc[:, 2:].isna().any(axis=1)]
```

---

```
print (df_drop)
  Last_Name First_Name   Age  Salary
2       Sam       Bill   NaN     NaN
3    Ronnie       Tony  70.0     NaN
```

Comment: My apologies. I wrongly posted expected output. I edited my expected output. Please refer again. Sorry.